# change android emulator skin on adt bundle

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, adt, skin

Hello everybody i'm trying to change the android emulator skin in the latest adt bundle for linux (android developers tools given by android developer site here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). i have download skins from this link http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/ but they don't appear on the devices dropdown field even when i put them in the skin directory(/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-8/skins). there is no browsable skin field that can help me to use my new skins.

[image]

So if someone have a solution for me it will be helpfull.

Comment: Why are you wanting to change the skin for the emulator?
If you want to take a screenshot with a actual device frame around the screenshot, theres the device frame generator in http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was realy usefull but not exactly what i was looking for. i just want to work with another look of my emulator, i want it to look like a real phone. it works for many others people easyly but it does'nt work for me this is why asked my question.                                                             PS: apology if my english is not correct i use to speak french.